# SQL Limit results per column value

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

I'm trying to write a query that will function like a `LIMIT` statement, but it will limit the results returned per distinct column value instead of the entire result set. I don't know the terminology to explain what I want precisely, so I'll use an example.

In this example (which is a much simplified version of what I'm actually trying to do) I'm trying to `SELECT` the 5 most recent messages for each user in the system. The below table maps userIDs to messageIDs. Message IDs are assigned chronologically so a more recent message will have a higher ID value.

```
TABLE Messages (
 userId int,
 messageId int
)
```

Comment: You need a [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query. What RDBMS? MySQL?

Comment: Also see others here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT userId, messageId FROM (
    SELECT userId, messageId,
        if(@uid = userId, @cnt := @cnt + 1, (@cnt := 0 || @uid := userId)) cnt
    FROM Messages
    ORDER BY userId, messageId DESC
) msg_list
WHERE cnt <= 5;
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but only works if you can order by userId (unfortunately)